# Private domain-wide (published) Add-on not visible in marketplace search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, publish, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I've followed the following instructions...

Publishing an Add-on

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish

Then followed these instructions....

Publishing Add-ons for Domain-Wide Installation

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide

No errors, but the add-on refuses to appear in the private published apps list, with the following message "There are no private apps published for your domain".

The status of my project is listed as:

```
Published

GAM: Published
```

I've ticked the "Publish in Google Apps Marketplace"

I've ticked "Private / Everyone at mydomain.com" as the visibility

I've enabled the "Apps Marketplace SDK", configured the consent form and the configuration tab.

If I drill down on my published project in the chrome web store developer dashboard I see the installation page which has the [Free] and [share icon] buttons.  I can install the add-on if I click on the [Free] button.

However, the Add-on does not appear on any marketplace add-on list, whether I filter for the add-on name or if I filter the marketplace by my domain.

It's missing from the marketplace search within a google document, it's also missing from the Admin console.  The only place it's present is within the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard.

I'm expecting to be able to search/locate my add-in from the Admin console, along with button to deploy the add-on to all users in the domain.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you don't get an answer to your problem, it could be a bug in the publishing system of the Apps Marketplace.  In that case you'd need to report it.  There is a category for:  ***Public Trackers > G Suite Developers > G Suite Marketplace*** in the issue tracker.  [https://issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: What is the cloud project number?

Comment: Hi, very good write up of the issue. Sorry I don't have anything to add except I have having the exact same issue. (Taken the exact same steps.)