# Domain Wide Editor Add-on not found in Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-addons

I've published a domain-wide sheets add-on using this guide https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-for-domains

- The GCP project is setup and the Visibility is set to "My Domain"
- In the Chrome Web Store the project status is "Published" and "GAM: Published"
- In the Chrome Web Store the visibility option is set to Private -> Everyone at [domain]

I've received no errors and it's been 12 hours since publishing and the guide says it should be a few minutes to an hour.

In our domains admin panel I then goto Apps -> + -> Expand the Hamburger -> "[Domain] Apps" where domain-wide add-ons are found but there's no add-on listed.

[image]

I'm not sure what to try next. Any help?

Comment: What is the cloud project number?

Comment: @AlejandroTamalet I just updated thread. It's now appearing along with a 2nd project I published which also couldn't be found in the GAM. It's possible this was a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between 3 and 4 days the project finally appeared in the domain app section of the GAM.

I'm assuming this was a bug since I also published a 2nd test project 2 days after the first project which also didn't show up in the domain app section of the GAM but both the 1st and 2nd projects showed up (seemingly at the same time) in the GAM between 3 and 4 days after I published the 1st project.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861395/private-domain-wide-published-add-on-not-visible-in-marketplace-search#comment90675297_51861395), it could be a bug in the publishing system of the Apps Marketplace.

> In that case you'd need to report it. There is a category for: **Public Trackers > G Suite Developers > G Suite Marketplace** in the issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com